# Ember - RequireJS

Tags: jquery, ember.js, requirejs, handlebars.js

Can anyone help in identifying why the following Ember.js/Require.js application fails to render the index view?  The Ember segment works 100% in isolation.

**application.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script data-main="../script/application" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.4/require.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars-template" data-template-name="index">
      login page
      <a href="#" {{action "login"}}>Login</a>
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars-template" data-template-name="application">
      {{outlet}}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**application.js**

```
require(["library/jquery", "library/handlebars", "library/ember"], function() {
    Application = Ember.Application.create({
        LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
    });

    Application.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({});

    Application.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
        login: function() {
            console.log("called login controller method.");
        }
    });

    Application.Router.map(function() {
        this.route("index", {
            path: "/login" 
        });
    }); 
});
```

I have confirmed that the following files are successfully loaded by Require and that no script errors show in Safari or Chrome browsers.

- application.html

  - application.js
  - ember.js
  - handlebars.js
  - jquery.js
  - require.min.js

**Version information**

Require: 2.1.4

jQuery: v1.9.1

Ember: v1.0.0-rc.1

Handlebars: 1.0.0-rc.3

Comment: I also found requirejs hard to use with other libraries and vice-versa. That is why I created a library which is much easier to use and is tested with angular. There is a demo application at the bottom: gngeorgiev.github.io/Modulerr.js You can also combine all scripts into one without the dependency to Modulerr.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after sometime of head banging and a nights kip.  I've finally got an example of Ember & Require playing nice.

https://github.com/ben-crowhurst/EmberRequireSetup

A few issues were found relating to loading of application modules/ dependencies, coupled with the timing of Ember setup and DOM parsing.

Comment: I think someone may have beat you to it. https://github.com/zeflasher/ember-require-js

Answer (score 2):

The problem could be caused by not passing the dependencies to the function body. Not doing that would only work if all the dependencies 'mounted' themselves in the global scope (and one of the benefits of `requirejs` is that you can stop worrying about that altogether).

Try this:

```
require(["library/jquery", "library/handlebars", "library/ember"],
  function($, handlebars, Ember) {

    // verify that none of these is undefined
    console.log($, handlebars, Ember);

    var Application = Ember.Application.create({
        LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
    });

    (...)
});
```

If any of the variables printed to the console is still `undefined` that's a sign that your `requirejs` configuration is incorrect. I can highly recommend Chrome's development tools: you can set a breakpoint in the first line of the function body and investigate local/closure scope when the application is frozen. "Pause on uncaught exceptions" also helps a lot.

Also, it's a good idea to avoid creating global objects from within modules (that's why I added a `var` to the Application variable); one of the purposes of modules is to strictly limit what 'leaks' outside.

Lastly, I'm not convinced `requirejs` would work with `Handlebars` code stored inside the `<script>` tags. It's not even guaranteed `Handlebars` will be loaded by the time browser processes that part of `application.html`. I've never used `handlebars` but if that's the case I'm sure the correct way of handling this is somewhere on SO already :).